# Python - Convert string to command

Tags: python

I'm currently creating a script that'll loop run a set of Subprocess, and then wait for all the subprocess to finish. I have to add variables in to the subprocess before running them, so I was thinking of writing it as a string, and then converting the string to a command? Would something like that exist?

For example, I have these stringss:

```
"p1 = subprocess.Popen('python','hello.py')"
"p2 = subprocess.Popen('python','hello2.py')"
```

How would I execute it to be able to call p1 or p2 later on in the script? (E.g p1.wait())

Comment: Since you're running Python files, you could consider using the `multiprocessing` module instead if it suits you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using strings is a bad idea, I'd use a list:

```
options = [('python','hello.py'), ('python','hello2.py')]
for option in options:
    process = subprocess.Popen(option) 
    #do something here
```

Comment: You probably want to save the result of `subprocess.Popen`: `processes = [subprocess.Popen(option) for option in options]`

Comment: If 'python' is always used, you don't need to keep repeating it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("p1 = subprocess.Popen('python','hello.py')")
```

Note that `exec` *executes* statements, while `eval` *evaulates* expressions.

But I agree with the other answer that it's better to do this in a different way if you can. One thing you should definitely never do is execute arbitrary strings whose source you don't know, for instance if they could come from a user.

Comment: ... also note that `exec`ing random strings is a very bad practice.